# ACF, Wordpress, How to Display all custom fields with loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need create page that will display all custom fields from user profile.
So for example it should be like:

**field1** : value

**field2** : value

**field3** : value

**field4** : value

......

Amount of fields will be changing

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $all_meta = get_user_meta($user_id); 
foreach($all_meta as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' - ' . $value[0];
} ?>
```

It requires knowing the user ID. you can add styling/html tags as needed.

Let me know if it works!